# Can adaptive card in MS Team be submitted to arbitrary server?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a client request to use adaptive card in MS Team as a front-end for some business process.  They have their own business servers.  I would like to try to achieve that without having to build a chat server, is it possible to have Adaptive Card submit form inputs to an arbitrary server, preferably being able to set the URL endpoint when I call the Graph API to send the card in the first place?

Comment: Technically...thats what you do. You configure an App and a Bot registration. The Bot registration has a url where it sends the data to. The server you point it to can be anything as long as you format the responses that MS Teams can understand them. You don't have to use the botframework it just makes things a shitton easier.

Comment: OK I understand, you are right, I ended up going with a Google Cloud Function solution

Comment: @TimCadenbach Can you specify EXACTLY where I can set this?

Comment: If you install the AppStudio app in MS Teams it guides you through everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Tim Cadenbach comments

Technically...thats what you do. You configure an App and a Bot registration. The Bot registration has a url where it sends the data to. The server you point it to can be anything as long as you format the responses that MS Teams can understand them. You don't have to use the botframework it just makes things a shitton easier.